# GPO extension to MPG and MPEG files

Tags: group-policy

I have a 2008 R2 server with GPO that [generates pop-up menus on extensions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754587.aspx) of GPG , MPG and MPEG files. This GPO is active in encoding servers. options that appear on the gpg files , mpeg , mpg are " encrypt ", " decryption "

Case in point: When you create a file on a server encoding , the context menu appears well on GPG files. But not on mpeg and mpg files. It has already run before but for some reason it does not work ^ ^

If I change the options in the GPO for MPG and MPEG and I put another extension like foo, bar or tata or anything other , it works .... It is as if the system was allergic extensions MPG and MPEG files. Of course , I tested a deletion of the GPO to MPG extension, but it's still the same problem. And I encounter exactly the same problems with the MPEG extension

What is the class associated with the extension is important and could have an impact on the implementation of this gpo ?

Thank you for your future responses ^ ^

Comment: Tell us what GPO you're doing this with and what settings it's using.

Comment: File extensions call scripts that allow encryption / unlocking files with MPG, MPEG or GPG extensions.

Concrete example:

- In gpmc.msc> I create a file extension "gpg", I choose the associated class and then I choose what will appear in my context menu> "encryption" "unlocking"

So from the client or the GPO is applied when I right-click on a file with GPG for example, I see the options "encryption" "unlocking". But on files with extensions MPG or MPEG, I do not see these options!

Hoping to have been a little more clear ^ ^

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I haven't seen this gp setting before.

Comment: This parameter can be found at:

Computer Configuration> Parameter Control Panel> Folder Options

Then on the right window, you can add extensions to files of any type

That's why you ask?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was curious about.  I have never noticed that policy function before.

Comment: I noticed something else:

If I change the gpo extension mpg file that any other extension (eg "bart") it works. I'm going on the machine connected to the GPO and I create a "test.bart" file. I right-click on it and it is nickel I see the shortcut "unlock" menu. It is as if there was residue on the old server the barrier to apply this gpo or update correctly. Yet I restart the server three times since ^ ^